# Ember - Path or pattern "vendor/ic-ajax/dist/named-amd/main.js" did not match any files

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, npm, package

I have an ember app with ember-cli running perfectly on my MacBook Pro. Now I've installed ember on another MacBook Pro, downloaded the same git repo and ran `ember s`, which gives me this error trace:

```
compiler.js:17942:7)
    Walker.visit (/Users/Jensherf/shopstar-u/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:17910:12)
    visitors.Program (/Users/Jensherf/shopstar-u/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:17919:16)
Path or pattern "vendor/ic-ajax/dist/named-amd/main.js" did not match any files
Error: Path or pattern "vendor/ic-ajax/dist/named-amd/main.js" did not match any files
    at Object.multiGlob (/Users/Jensherf/shopstar-u/node_modules/broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers/index.js:203:13)
    at Class.module.exports.CachingWriter.extend.addFiles (/Users/Jensherf/shopstar-u/node_modules/broccoli-sourcemap-concat/concat-with-maps.js:74:13)
    at Class.module.exports.CachingWriter.extend.updateCache (/Users/Jensherf/shopstar-u/node_modules/broccoli-sourcemap-concat/concat-with-maps.js:52:12)
    at /Users/Jensherf/shopstar-u/node_modules/broccoli-sourcemap-concat/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:92:34
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/Users/Jensherf/shopstar-u/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:489:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/Users/Jensherf/shopstar-u/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:501:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (/Users/Jensherf/shopstar-u/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:472:11)
    at Object.lib$rsvp$asap$$flush [as _onImmediate] (/Users/Jensherf/shopstar-u/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1290:9)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:345:15)
```

In this output, the sentence "`Path or pattern "vendor/ic-ajax/dist/named-amd/main.js" did not match any files`" is in red.

I cannot figure out how to fix this. Why would the app be looking in the `vendor/` folder for this library? Shouldn't it be in bower components or node modules? Does anyone have an idea what should be in this file?

Here is my .gitignore file just for completeness:

```
# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# compiled output
/dist
/tmp

# dependencies
/node_modules
/bower_components

# misc
/.sass-cache
/connect.lock
/coverage/*
/libpeerconnection.log
npm-debug.log
testem.log
```

Comment: `npm install && bower install`

Comment: Already tried that @Kitler

Comment: Node version? cli version? bower version?

Comment: Node.js: `v10.31`. Ember-cli: `v0.2.1`. Bower: `v1.4.1`

Comment: Is the node version on the mac that works the same?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81871/discussion-between-kitler-and-marco-prins).

Comment: It sounds like you didn't commit a dependency

Comment: Commit? Are you talking about a git commit? @runspired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an issue on `ember-cli-ic-ajax` repo that might be the answer.

> 0.2.0 is only valid with a future version of ember-cli, you should use 0.1.4

https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-ic-ajax/issues/11

Answer (score -1):

Do you have an entry for "ember-cli-ic-ajax" in package.json? If not it's because you forgot to --save when you installed it on the other machine. You can just do *npm install --save ember-cli-ic-ajax* on the first laptop (or just edit the file manually) then commit your changes and all should be good.

Comment: My node_modules is ignored by git, how can this work?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error. What solved it for me was `bower install ic-ajax --save`. Hopefully this is helpful to anyone else.

Comment: Made absolutely no difference at all